# How can I start appending to a specific row in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am creating a program that would allow the user to input information about themselves and store it in an Excel file. However, whenever the program is used for another time, I would want their information to be stored right after the inputs of the previous user. This is after closing the previous program

I have already done the code needed to read the rows to see if there is content written. I just need to start appending after it sees that there is no content on that row. Lets just say I want to start appending at row 2, how would I do that?
The program is something like this:

```
  import openpyxl
  wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Example.xlsx')
  ws = wb.active
  Main_List = []
  while True:
     asking = input('Would you like to input info? y/n: ')
     if asking.upper() =='N':
        break
     name = input('Name: ')
     age = input('Age: ')
     sex = input('Sex: ')
     My_List = [name, age, sex]
     Main_List.append(My_List)

  for row in Main_List:
     ws.append(row)
```

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? openpyxl always appends to the next row, which sounds like what you want to do.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. However, I would like to do that after I close the program and open it again. The thing that is happening is that it always starts from the top again and overwrites what is already written

Comment: To make it more simple: Let's just say I want to start appending at row 2. How would I do that

Comment: openpyxl does not append to the first row if a file already has content. It will always check the `max_row`

Comment: It always starts appending to the first row if I close the program and use it again. As I start the program, I want it to read the content and start wherever it is empty.

Comment: Nevermind I got it. Thanks @CharlieClark